# No electrical power

Tags: motorcycle

I recently bought a V-star 650, the dude told me that he replaced the battery with a smaller one and that’s why it had no electrical power. I replaced the battery with the correct size still nothing no horn no lights. I replaced all fuses including the main fuse and still nothing. Please help I’m getting extremely frustrated.

Comment: If you replaced the fuse and plug it into a battery that you know is working then it is probably a short in the lights/horn.  You'll have to test those wires for continuity with a multimeter to know for sure.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. I agree with @AlexW that a short is possible. As annoying as it is though, I'd recommend opening things up and tracing wires and harnesses to make sure everything is plugged in and/or bolted on solidly. From there you can start diagnosing for shorts more easily, and you'll have enough familiarity with the system to make better decisions. Also, if you could add the year, it may help other users to give better diagnostic advice.

Answer (score 1):

did you check the switch on ACC? any voltage on acc switch?

use volt meter / multimeter to check battery voltage, fuse with acc on. and check on switch if there is voltage across it.

the switch and connector on fuse box / battery could be the main culprits

Comment: Good idea, basically you can test the main fuse by checking for voltage on "one side of it" and also on the "output side" ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad, and difficult to comprehensively answer in this venue.  I suggest you find a automotive - electrical text book, and follow the general recommendations in that book.

You will want to verify that the ignition switch works. Any load relays work.  The fuse panel is correctly distributing power, etc.  You will need a voltmeter, and it will be helpful to have some alligator clip jumper wires.  Since your battery is not charging, it may be helpful to have a battery charger available as well.

The debug is rather easy to do, but requires a little more content than can be written in this venue.  You may also find "illustrated" instruction in the form of youtube videos.